# Youtube [Data-API] LiveChat where logged-in user is moderator

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to work out how i get a list of videos/streams where the user is a moderator for live chat.

This is done in [nightbot](https://beta.nightbot.tv) and [fussbot](http://fussbot.io) but i can't work out how they do it, it works by you adding the Nightbot channel as a moderator of your live streams chat but im unsure how they get your live stream to watch the chat from them being added as a moderator to the channel. (i'm guessing they are a channel moderator and not a video/stream as they are persistent though all casts)

I have thought it would be in the API docs but if it is i can't find it / not sure what im looking for.

I'm implementing this in PHP and so far i have it now getting stream events id's and your persistent live stream ids but i'm now stuck.

Comment: to say Youtube/Google Developer support should have seen this as per https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support it's a joke they not responded with anything...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the API supports a way to retrieve a list of chats where the logged-in user is a moderator. The liveChatModerators.list method requires that a value be set for the liveChatId parameter, and that value must specify a single live chat ID.

I'll caveat the following by saying that I'm not familiar with the apps you mentioned or how they work, so this is just conjecture. Your question describes a third-party app that lets you (or helps you to) manage YouTube live chats. Presumably, to use the app, you must have granted that app permission to manage your YouTube account.

With that in mind, if you set up a live stream through that app, then the app could, while creating the live stream, also use the liveChatModerators.insert method to add its own channel as a moderator to the live stream's chat. Similarly, the app could retrieve your list of live streams and add its own channel as a moderator to any of those live streams. The app could use its own data store to determine whether its channel had already been added as a moderator for any particular chat.

Please post a comment in reply if you don't think I'm understanding your question.

Comment: Possibly but that must mean night bot are burning though API Rate limit queries checking if the chat is live for every user and that seems impossible to maintain.